# K&R possible bug in polish calculator

Tags: c, stack, calculator, polish

I'm not sure where to post this but I think I found a pretty major bug in K&R's polish calculator program. Basically, when you perform an operation, two values get popped while only the result gets pushed. The problem is that the result isn't getting pushed to the top of the stack! Here's an illustration:

[image: Polish calculator bug]

The full code for the polish calculator provided by the textbook is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atof() */

#define MAXOP 100 /* max size of operand or operator */
#define NUMBER '0' /* signal that a number was found */

int getop(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);

/* reverse Polish calculator */
main()
{
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];

    while ((type= getop(s)) != EOF) {
        switch (type) {
        case NUMBER:
            push(atof(s));
            break;
        case '+':
            push (pop() + pop()) ;
            break;
        case '*':
            push(pop() * pop());
            break;
        case '-':
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() - op2);
            break;
        case '/':
            op2 = pop();
            if (op2 != 0.0)
                push(pop() / op2);
            else
                printf("error: zero divisor\n");
            break;
        case '\n':
            printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
            break;
        default:
            printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
            break;
        }
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

#define MAXVAL 100 /* maximum depth of val stack */

int sp = 0; /* next free stack position */
double val[MAXVAL]; /* value stack */

/* push: push f onto value stack */
void push(double f)
{
    if ( sp < MAXVAL)
        val[sp++] = f;
    else
        printf("error: stack full. can't push %g\n", f);
}

/* pop: pop and return top value from stack */
double pop(void)
{
    if (sp > 0)
        return val[--sp];
    else {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}

#include <ctype.h>

int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

/* getop: get next operator or numeric operand */
int getop(char s[])
{
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c; /* not a number */
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c)) /*collect integer part*/
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.') /*collect fraction part*/
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}

#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* buffer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0; /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed back) character */
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c) /* push character back on input */
{
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}
```

If you want to check for yourself, all I did was add

```
static int pass = 0;
int i, check;
i = check = 0;
```

inside the while loop in main() and

```
if(!check) {
    printf("pass #%d\n",pass++);
    while(val[i] != '\0') {
        printf("val[%d]: %.2f\n",i,val[i]);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

at the end of the while loop, just after the switch statement. I also put `check = 1;` in the case for `'\n'`.

As a possible workaround I re-wrote the pop function such that popped values are removed from the val array as soon as they are accessed. So instead of

```
double pop(void)
{
    if (sp > 0)
        return val[--sp];
    else {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

you'd have something like

```
double pop(void)
{
    if (sp > 0) {
        double temp = val[--sp];
        val[sp] = '\0';
        return temp;
    }
    else {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

I also re-wrote the push function to ensure that values are always pushed to the end of the val array. So instead of

```
void push(double f)
{
    if ( sp < MAXVAL)
        val[sp++] = f;
    else
        printf("error: stack full. can't push %g\n", f);
}
```

you'd have

```
void push(double f)
{
    if ( sp < MAXVAL) {
        while (val[sp] != '\0')
            ++sp;
        val[sp++] = f;
    }
    else
        printf("error: stack full. can't push %g\n", f);
}
```

Even with these changes, I still had to re-write

```
case '\n':
        printf("\t%.8g\n", pop());
        break;
```

to retrieve the value at the top of the stack without popping it, which required replacing the `printf` statement with a simple function like

```
void print_top(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    while( val[i] != '\0' )
        ++i;
    --i;
    printf("\t%.8g\n",val[i]);
}
```

Only then does the polish calculator seem to function as intended, at least in terms of what the stack is doing behind the scenes. You can try it out for yourself with the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atof() */
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXOP 100 /* max size of operand or operator */
#define NUMBER '0' /* signal that a number was found */
#define MAXVAL 100 /* maximum depth of val stack */

int getop(char []);
void push(double);
double pop(void);
void print_top(void);

int sp = 0; /* next free stack position */
double val[MAXVAL]; /* value stack */

/* reverse Polish calculator */
main()
{
    int type;
    double op2;
    char s[MAXOP];

    while ((type= getop(s)) != EOF) {

        static int pass = 0;
        int i, check;
        i = check = 0;

        switch (type) {
        case NUMBER:
            push(atof(s));
            break;
        case '+':
            push (pop() + pop()) ;
            break;
        case '*':
            push(pop() * pop());
            break;
        case '-':
            op2 = pop();
            push(pop() - op2);
            break;
        case '/':
            op2 = pop();
            if (op2 != 0.0)
                push(pop() / op2);
            else
                printf("error: zero divisor\n");
            break;
        case '\n':
            print_top();
            check = 1;
            break;
        default:
            printf("error: unknown command %s\n", s);
            break;
        }
        if(!check) {
            printf("pass #%d\n",pass++);
            while(val[i] != '\0') {
                printf("val[%d]: %.2f\n",i,val[i]);
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}

/* push: push f onto value stack */
void push(double f)
{
    if ( sp < MAXVAL) {
        while (val[sp] != '\0')
            ++sp;
        val[sp++] = f;
    }
    else
        printf("error: stack full. can't push %g\n", f);
}

/* pop: pop and return top value from stack */
double pop(void)
{
    if (sp > 0) {
        double temp = val[--sp];
        val[sp] = '\0';
        return temp;
    }
    else {
        printf("error: stack empty\n");
        return 0.0;
    }
}

int getch(void);
void ungetch(int);

/* getop: get next operator or numeric operand */
int getop(char s[])
{
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c; /* not a number */
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c)) /*collect integer part*/
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.') /*collect fraction part*/
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}

#define BUFSIZE 100

char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* buffer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0; /* next free position in buf */

int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed back) character */
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}

void ungetch(int c) /* push character back on input */
{
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
    printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}

void print_top(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    while( val[i] != '\0' )
        ++i;
    --i;
    printf("\t%.8g\n",val[i]);
}
```

Note that I had to move most of my `#define` statements and prototype declarations to the beginning in order to accommodate for the debugging `printf`statement at the end of `main()`.

*Edited out some of my audacious claims :P

Comment: Nah. It's just that the stack grows upwards, i. e. `val[0]` is the bottom (and the top too if there's only one element). And at the time you print the result, `val[1]` is invalid, it has already been popped.

Comment: ` while (val[sp] != '\0')` looks wrong.

Comment: @wildplasser - you're absolutely right that it's absolutely wrong. ;-)

Comment: Correction: it **is** wrong.

Comment: "Considering this is the first problem in the book to introduce the concept of stacks, the fact that it uses stacks incorrectly seems like something worth pointing out" ... No, here's something worth pointing out: for those very reasons, it is extraordinarily unlikely that you are correct.

Comment: Whoa, just yesterday you were trying to figure out the difference between `*ptr` and `ptr`, and today you're posting *basic* bugs in the operation of K&R code that neither K&R nor any of their myriad readers spotted. Here's your word for the day (and the day after, and the day after that ..): **humility**

Comment: At least he *edited* himself towards humilty. (he will never become a capable C++ programmer, unfortunately)

Comment: "He will never become a capable C++ programmer, unfortunately" Why would you say that? I understand the other snarky comments were warranted, but not this.

Comment: Because no capable C++ programmer would ever work towards humility in response to snarky feedback. If a natural C++ programmer had asked this question, things would be *on fire* by now... (but seriously, kudos for taking the feedback in stride - hopefully this is a lesson for next time)

Comment: Yeah, I feel like an idiot right now after running Carl Norum's correction :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're thinking of the stack backwards - the top of the stack is in the highest valid index, not in `val[0]`.  This behaviour is evident when you look at the pushes of the operands.  Your output:

   ```
   3 4 +
   pass #0
   val[0]: 3.00
   pass #1
   val[0]: 3.00
   val[1]: 4.00
   ```

   First, the `3` is pushed - going onto the top of the (previously empty) stack - it's in slot 0.  Next `4` is pushed.  As you can see, it goes into `val[1]`, clearly showing that `val[0]` is not the top of the stack in this case.
2. You're printing the stack incorrectly, which is confusing you further.  Change your print loop to:

   ```
   while (i < sp) {
       printf("val[%d]: %.2f\n",i,val[i]);
       ++i;
   }
   ```

   That is, print only the valid entries in the stack, and you'll see your error.

   Your current comparison is looking for a `0` entry on the stack, which isn't how the program is identifying the free entries.  That's what the `sp` variable is used for.  In addition to looking for the wrong thing, it's doing it in a bizarro way - `val` is a an array of floating-point numbers - why are you comparing to a character literal `\0`?

   Here's the complete corrected output:

   ```
   3 4 +
   pass #0
   val[0]: 3.00
   pass #1
   val[0]: 3.00
   val[1]: 4.00
   pass #2
   val[0]: 7.00
       7
   ```

   Now, you see the correct output - both the `3.00` and `4.00` are popped, and `7.00` is pushed back onto the stack.  It's now the only valid entry.

Comment: Or- more probably- some printf() debugging.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  I generated the output by lifting the OP's code and fixing it.

Comment: "why are you comparing to a character literal \0?" -- Perhaps the OP  over-interpreted the notion of \0 as a "terminator".

Comment: Comparing to "\0" is my go-to trick for reaching the end of an array of arbitrary length. I suppose that only works for character arrays, so what do you generally do to reach the end of say, an int array?

Comment: You know how big it is and use a counter.  What if your `int` array has a zero in it?  In general, your trick doesn't work for character arrays, either - just for well-formed strings.

Answer (score 2):

Nah. It's just that the stack grows upwards, i. e. `val[0]` is the bottom (and the top too if there's only one element). And at the time you print the result, `val[1]` is invalid, it has already been popped.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug in the code given in K&R for reverse polish calculator.

It works only when the input is given in a single line.

If you press the enter then compiler will read `'\n'`,which results in (`case '\n':`) of the code and the pop function will be called.

#### Code result is in the given image:

[image]